# Cant start MySQL Server from XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

I am using xampp mySQL for Wordpress for more then one year and it is my first time that it is not working. When I start MySQL I am getting this error (it is german, and basically here stands, that it cant be started and check the if the port is in usage and open Log to get more information):

```
Fehler: MySQL wurde unerwartet beendet
17:01:03  [mysql]   Ursache könnte ein geblockter Port, fehlende Abhängigkeiten,
17:01:03  [mysql]   fehlende Berechtigungen, ein Absturz oder ein Abbruch einer anderen Methode sein.
17:01:03  [mysql]   Drücke den Logs Button um error logs zu sehen und prüfe
17:01:03  [mysql]   im Windows Event Viewer für weitere Hinweise
17:01:03  [mysql]   Wenn du weitere Hilfe benötigst, kopiere den kompletten Inhalt des Log Fensters
17:01:03  [mysql]   und füge ihn als Ergänzung in einem neuen Forum Eintrag hinzu.
```

I have checked if the port 3306 is free and it is (MySQL Server should run on that port).
I have also checked the mysql_error.log. This are the last lines:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk 
size = 16M
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. 
Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 240572804; transaction id 
221340
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-10-09 17:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201009 17:01:01
```

Can somebody please help me to fix this problem without uninstalling the xampp?

Comment: It would be lot faster for us if you could translate it to english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt solve that problem, so I just saved the dirs from /xampp/mysql/data with the names of my dbs on my local driver, and uninstalled xampp and then I installed xampp one more time and imported the dirs into /xampp/mysql/data. So in my case it does worked.